# Sales Grouped by Week of the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to output the number sales in a year to date in weekly format where Monday is the first day of the week and Sunday is the last.

The table structure is as follows.

SalesId | Representative | DateOfSale.

Below is what I have tried but it doesn't seem to give me the correct result. The counts don't seem to add up for a given week. The Sunday results are not included in the correct week. I am thinking it has something to do with the date not including 11:59:59.999 for the last day of the week.

```
 SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, Sales.DateOfSale), 6) as [Week Ending], count(SalesID) as Sales, 
        count(distinct(representative)) as Agents, count(SalesID) / count(distinct(representative)) as SPA
FROM Sales 
where DateOfSale >= DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0)
GROUP BY DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, Sales.DateOfSale), 6)
ORDER BY DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, Sales.DateOfSale), 6)
```

I am hoping to have something like this:

```
Week Ending | Sales
01/05/2014  | 5
01/12/2014  | 8
01/19/2014  | 11
01/26/2014  | 14
```

Please excuse the formatting of the table above. I couldn't seem to figure out how to create a pipe/newline based table using the editor.

~Nick

Comment: . . In StackOverflow, you can format code and tables just by putting four spaces in front of each row (no special tags).  You can do this for a region by selecting the region and clicking on the `{}` button above the edit window.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a table or table parameter that has all of your calendar information. In this case, it would need at minimum the column WeekEnding.

For example

```
DECLARE @MyCalendar TABLE
    (
    WeekEnding date
    );
```

Populate this with your valid WeekEnding dates. I might also make parameters to limit the amount of sales data, e.g. @BeginDate and @EndDate.

If you join using "<=" on the week ending date, then I believe you will get the return you want:

```
SELECT
    MyCalendar.WeekEnding,
    COUNT(Sales.SalesId) Sales,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Sales.Representative) Agents,
    CAST(COUNT(Sales.SalesId) AS float) / CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT Sales.Representative) AS float) Spa
FROM
    Sales
    INNER JOIN
    @MyCalendar MyCalendar
    ON
        Sales.DateOfSale <= MyCalendar.WeekEnding
WHERE
    Sales.DateOfSale BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY
    MyCalendar.WeekEnding;
```

I am assuming you are using SQL 2012, but I believe this will work in 2008 too. I might point out two other things. First, consider your data type when dividing the COUNT of SalesId by the distinct count of Representative. You may not get the return you expect, and that is why I cast as float. Second, you apply count distinct slightly differently than what I use; the extra parenthesis are not needed.

I have a simplified version in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e886b/1).